# How to extract table value from pdf using PYPDF2?

Tags: python, text, pypdf

I am trying to search through a pdf file to find the value associated with "Unit of Issue" or UI. I have a lot of pdfs to look through with potentially varying format. Here's a sample [pdf](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/honeybox-catalogue.appspot.com/o/test.pdf?alt=media&token=f540b8f2-9d99-4d29-8bca-8f7d7070f9f9) and below is a screenshot of the top of the page with the table:

[image: screenshot of pdf page 6]

I would like to extract

UI:EA

on page 6. is there a way to accomplish this?

this is the code I use to open the file

```
import PyPDF2

try:
   pdfFileObj = open('test.pdf', 'rb')
   pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
   pageNumber = pdfReader.numPages
   page = pdfReader.getPage(0)
   print(pageNumber)

   pagecontent = page.extractText()
   print(pagecontent)
except Exception as e:
   print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using other tools, the following method is easier in my opinion.

Use the Bash command `pdftotext`. It extracts all the text inside the PDF and saves it in a text file.
Then use `grep` to find the line that contains the value of UI.
After testing on several of your PDF's, if the result of `grep` has a fixed pattern, use `cut` to get the value from this pattern.

```sh
pdftotext test.pdf  # this creates a test.txt file
grep "UI QUANTITY" test.txt  # output: UI QUANTITY EA 81.000
```

If the value you are looking for is always the third word in the output of the above command, then pipe it to `cut` to get the value:

```sh
grep "UI QUANTITY" test.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 3
```

You can make the whole process into a script (reading PDF's, extracting text, finding the value, writing the results to a file).